# Installing speeqe (XMPP/ejabberd) in a local development environment

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

To a non-developer [this](https://github.com/thepug/Speeqe/wiki/SpeeqeSetup) installation guide is very hard to get through. I'm on Mac OS X 10.6, I have apache and ejabberd installed (which is the bare minumum it says).

I have a few questions to get it up and running.

Where do I clone the git repository to on my computer? My desktop, /Users/fred/sites folder, or somewhere else?

are my HTTP DOMAIN and XMPP DOMAIN macpro.local (my local address) or localhost or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development purposes, I've been successfully using the e[jabberd TurnKey Linux Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/ejabberd) that combines ejabberd with Speeqe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're still interested, but the domains are going to have to be the network visible ones.

Your xmpp domain is how you would log in to the ejabberd server eg:

`user@yourxmppservername.com` if it is your local machine this might just be your ip address, but not `macpro.local` because then only your computer would be able to see it.